# How to measure from the right to the button I placed at the top right in a SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I added a button in the top right. But I want to measure the button from the right and from the top in a way that is compatible with all screens.

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to measure the distance between the top trailing corner of the button and the top right corner of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use GeometryReader?

```
 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Width: \(geometry.size.width)")
                Text("Height: \(geometry.size.height)")
            }
        }
    }
```

The GeometryReader component is a view container that allows access to its size and position. In this way we can correctly align elements and equalize view sizes.